# emacs multi-keystroke binding

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm still very new to EMACS, but are getting familiar when i'm going through the emacs and elisp manual.  But right now i'm stuck on this:

Is there a simple way to bind input sequences in regexp style?

eg: the default binding for function enlarge-window-horizontally is "C-x {", is it possible to rebind it to something like "C-x ({)+" so that enlarge-window-horizontally can be called repeatedly by repeating "{" character, instead of release Ctrl key multiple times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another way to archive what you desire:

The first time you want to repeat the last command, press <kbd>C-x z</kbd>, afterwards you may repeat your command as often as desired by just pressing <kbd>z</kbd>.

The advantage of this approach is that it works with every command you use and not just for a specific one.

For additional reference here is the output of <kbd>C-h f</kbd>

> ## 8.11 Repeating a Command
>
> Many simple commands, such as those invoked with a single key or with
>   <kbd>M-x COMMAND-NAME</kbd> , can be repeated by invoking them with a
>   numeric argument that serves as a repeat count (*note Arguments::).
>   However, if the command you want to repeat prompts for input, or uses
>   a numeric argument in another way, that method won't work.
>
> The command <kbd>C-x z</kbd> (`repeat') provides another way to repeat an
>   Emacs command many times.  This command repeats the previous Emacs
>   command, whatever that was.  Repeating a command uses the same
>   arguments that were used before; it does not read new arguments each
>   time.
>
> To repeat the command more than once, type additional <kbd>z</kbd>'s: each
>   <kbd>z</kbd> repeats the command one more time.  Repetition ends when you type
>   a character other than <kbd>z</kbd>, or press a mouse button.
>
> For example, suppose you type <kbd>C-u 2 0 C-d</kbd> to delete 20
>   characters. You can repeat that command (including its argument) three
>   additional times, to delete a total of 80 characters, by typing <kbd>C-x z
>   z z</kbd>.  The first <kbd>C-x z</kbd> repeats the command once, and each subsequent
>   <kbd>z</kbd> repeats it once again.

Answer (score 1):

The "Emacs way" is to use <kbd>C-u</kbd> as a prefix key. E.g. <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>{</kbd>.

Having said that, it's possible to do what you ask for. However, it would require you to bind <kbd>C-x {</kbd> and <kbd>{</kbd> separately. The former would be defined like it is today, but the latter would have to look something like:

```
(defun my-open-brace ()
  (interactive)
  (if (eq last-command 'shrink-window-horizontally)
      (progn
        (setq this-command 'shrink-window-horizontally)
        (call-interactively 'shrink-window-horizontally))
    (call-interactively 'self-insert-command)))
```

Unfortunately, if you have many sequences ending in <kbd>{</kbd>, you would have to write one function to handle them all.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define your own repeatable command and bind it to `C-x {`.  You can then use it *exactly* as you requested: `C-x { { { {`..., instead of having to use `C-x { C-x z z z z`...

Here is what you do:

```
 (defun your-repeat-command (command)
   "Repeat COMMAND."
   (let ((repeat-message-function  'ignore))
     (setq last-repeatable-command  command)
     (repeat nil)))


 (defun your-shrink-window-horizontally ()
   "Shrink window horizontally.
 You can repeat this by hitting the last key again..."
   (interactive)
   (require 'repeat nil t)
   (my-repeat-command 'shrink-window-horizontally))


 (define-key ctl-x-map "{" 'your-shrink-window-horizontally)
```

You can do this with any command you like --- use `my-repeat-command` to make a repeatable version of it.  I do this all the time, in several of my libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Write a multi repeat command for emacs by using minor mode. I name it smart-repeat-mode

https://github.com/zhsfei/emacs-ext