# Automatic creation of repeatable command

Tags: emacs, elisp

There are already [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201738/how-to-write-a-key-bindings-in-emacs-for-easy-repeat) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382708/emacs-multi-keystroke-binding) on the topic of *repeatable emacs commands* (i.e. the behaviour of `C-x z` [`repeat-command`], where each subsequent `z` repeats the last command), however, none of the *automatic solutions* can cope with non-prefix keybindings (My terminology: `C-c p` is a prefix keybinding with prefix `C-c`, the keystroke `M-s-+` on the other hand is a non-prefix keybinding).

In my setup I have bound `M-s-+` to `text-scale-increase` and `M-s--` to `text-scale-decrease`. It would be nice to just hit `+` or `-` for repeated zooming after the initial command. This can be achieved by the following piece of elisp:

```lisp
(defvar text-scale-temp-keymap (make-sparse-keymap))
(define-key text-scale-temp-keymap (kbd "+") 'text-scale-increase)
(define-key text-scale-temp-keymap (kbd "-") 'text-scale-decrease)

(defun text-scale-increase-rep (inc)
  (interactive "p")
  (text-scale-increase inc)
  (set-temporary-overlay-map text-scale-temp-keymap t))

(defun text-scale-decrease-rep (inc)
  (interactive "p")
  (text-scale-decrease inc)
  (set-temporary-overlay-map text-scale-temp-keymap t))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-s-+") 'text-scale-increase-rep)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s--") 'text-scale-decrease-rep)
```

However, to repeat this code every time I want to create a repeatable keybinding is cumbersome and unnecessary. I'm asking for a way to automatise the task. Image this code

```lisp
(make-repeatable-command 'text-scale-increase '(("+" . text-scale-increase) 
                                                ("-" . text-scale-decrease)))
```

would create the command named `text-scale-increase-rep` and an overlay keymap named `text-scale-increase-temporary-map` with the corresponding keys.

I assume this is possible, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defun defrepeatable (alist)
  (lexical-let ((keymap (make-sparse-keymap))
                (func (cdar alist)))
    (mapcar (lambda(x) (define-key keymap (car x) (cdr x))) alist)
    (lambda (arg)
      (interactive "p")
      (funcall func arg)
      (set-temporary-overlay-map keymap t))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-z")
                (defrepeatable
                    '(("+" . text-scale-increase) 
                      ("-" . text-scale-decrease))))
```

Comment: As far as I see this does the same as the linked solutions: it can only be used for _prefix style_ keystrokes a la `C-z +` `+` `+` and can not be used for the desired `M-s-+` `+` `+` case.

Comment: Works with `C-M-+ + -` and `M-+ + -` and `M-s-+ + -` although with the latter is a bit ridiculous
to press 4 keys at once.

Comment: If I replace `C-z` (your code) by `M-s` and enter `M-s-+` I get the error message `M-s-+ is undefined` (tried in `emacs -Q` only added `(require 'cl)`).

Comment: You should put `M-s-+`, not `M-s`.

Comment: Aha! Ok, did that, now I get the error message: `funcall: Symbol's value as variable is void: alist` [Still in `emacs -Q`].

Comment: Now it's working! For educational purposes: Can you explain why it wasn't working before?

Comment: Before `alist` was in lambda but not in lexical-let, so the lambda did not see it. It was working in my instance of Emacs because I've bound `alist` as a global variable during debugging. In summary: if you want lambda to see anything that's not its arg or global, use `lexical-let`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative --

You do not need all of that, if all you want to do is (a) define a repeatable command and (b) bind it to a (repeatable) key.

The solution I presented in the pages ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21353393/729907), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20535110/729907)) that you linked to, applies here too.  The point of that solution was *not* that it is *limited* to use with a prefix key but that you can ***also*** use it to repeat a key that is on a prefix key.

Here is the same solution, applied to your example.  You only need to define `repeat-command` once -- you can use it to define any number of repeatable commands.

```
(defun repeat-command (command)
  "Repeat COMMAND."
 (interactive)
 (let ((repeat-previous-repeated-command  command)
       (last-repeatable-command           'repeat))
   (repeat nil)))

(defun text-scale-increase-rep (inc)
  (interactive "p")
  (repeat-command 'text-scale-increase))

(defun text-scale-decrease-rep (inc)
  (interactive "p")
  (repeat-command 'text-scale-decrease))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-s-+") 'text-scale-increase-rep)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s--") 'text-scale-decrease-rep)
```